Dialogflow CX Match Confidence goes over 1.0
I'm using DialogFlow CX (I'm using a datastore agent, trained with faqs in a csv file) and I have noticed (since few days) that the match confidence value has changed. Until last week, the range was [0.0, 1.0) (as the documentation says), but now it returns even values over 1.0!
I don't know what happened but this is seriously misleading, especially considering that the confidence value should be a normalized value (like it was before, correctly).
I tried to create new agents and see if this was a temporary problem, but it is like that still.

Hi @Mauro Russo, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
